# Passing props with screen option in DrawerNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I am using DrawerNavigator in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer.

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen,
    },
    Notifications: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
    },
});
```

I have multiple screens that are using `MyNotificationsScreen` component with different props.

How can I do something like:

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen,
    },
    Notifications1: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen(propName=val1),
    },
    Notifications2: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen(propName=val2),
    },
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better way in many cases I think:

```
screen: (props) => <MyNotificationsScreen {...props} propName={val1} />
```

This will put your nav props in props.navigation.state.params.  If you want them to appear in this.props instead (which will mean your component is not tightly coupled to react-navigation) then use:

```
screen: (props) => <MyNotificationsScreen {...props.navigation.state.params} propName={val1} />
```

Comment: What is val1 here it tell me cannot find variable val1

Comment: @sushilbharwani it's just an example - the same one in the question.  You can define any properties you want.

Answer (score -3):

You do have two options here:

1- You pass the parameter in the 'navigate call':

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications1', {propName: 'val1'})
```

2- The other way around is to create Notifications1

```
class Notifications1 
{
  render ( )
  {
    return <MyNotificationsScreen propName="val1" />
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer does not relates with the question aksed