# How to pass params to DrawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

TL**D**R: I have a Login screen where user logs in and navigates to second screen. There I want to open the menu and have the user name appear as text. How can I pass the user name to the menu? (DrawerNavigator).

Some samples of my code below.

Router:

```
import MyMenu from './MyMenu';

const MyStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Home: {screen: Home}
  // more screens...
});

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Main: { screen: MyStack }
},
  { contentComponent: MyMenu }
);
```

Home Screen:

```
openMenu() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen', userName);
}
```

MyMenu:

```
render() {
  const userName = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  return (
    <View>
          <Text>{userName}</Text>
          // more stuff
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think it is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248403/passing-props-with-screen-option-in-drawernavigator)

Comment: Thanks for the thread. It works for static props - unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. This.props.navigation.state.params is always undefined in MyMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
import MyMenu from './MyMenu';

const MyStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Home: {screen: Home}
  // more screens...
});

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Main: { screen:({navigation}) => <MyStack screenProps={drawerNavigation:navigation}/> }
},
  { contentComponent: MyMenu }
);
```

Then you can access drawer's navigation from your Stack navigation like below.

```
this.props.screenProps.drawerNavigation.DO_WHATEVER
```

Comment: I already found a working solution, but I will test your suggestion as well later today. It does seem like what I was originally looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DrorBar Yeap. If it does not work, correct it like this `screenProps={{drawerNavigation:navigation}}`

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj I made a sample with 'react-navigation'. It might help you. https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-sample

Comment: Side menu is open now but i am very confusing when i hit login api after that i pass params to DrawerNavigator and but how can i pass params value into contentComponent: MyMenu

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props to your MyMenu Component:

Router:

```
    export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
      Main: { screen: MyStack }
    },
      { contentComponent: (props) => <MyMenu {...props} /> }
    );
```

Home Screen:

```
openMenu() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen', {userName: userName});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. This causes an error in MyMenu that this.props.navigation.state.params.userName is not defined. I might try and look for a different approach to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after spending so much time on this, I finally found a solution.
Simply put, you can only send navigation props when navigating to a new screen - 'DrawerOpen' does not count for this.

To solve this I had to change my structure a little bit, instead of having the DrawerNavigator as the root drawer, I have a StackNavigator as the root drawer.

Before:

```
const MyStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Home: {screen: Home}
  // more screens...
});

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Main: { screen: MyStack }
},
  { contentComponent: MyMenu }
);
```

After:

```
const MyStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  // more screens...
});

const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Main: { screen: MyStack }
},
  { contentComponent: MyMenu }
);

export const RootStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Drawer: {
     screen: MyDrawer,
     navigationOptions: { header: null } } //prevent double header
});
```

Now in Login screen I navigate to Drawer like this:

```
_login() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Drawer', { userName: userName });
}
```

And finally in MyMenu (which is part of 'Drawer'):

```
render() {
  const { userName } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  return (
    <View>
          <Text>{userName}</Text>
          // more stuff
    </View>
  );
}
```

It works!

Comment: By using this   Home: {screen: Home} this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined and for MyMenu  this.props.navigation.state.params is work well how fix for Home screen

Comment: My first screen is Login screen. From Login I navigate to Home screen using: this.props.navigation.navigate('Drawer', { userName: userName });

Comment: ok but when i press back button on android it's navigate to login screen and other thing is work good thank you but how resolve this issue

Comment: "but how resolve this issue" - which issue are you referring to? Is this.props.navigation.state.params still undefined in Home screen? it's working fine for me. Perhaps you should ask a new question and show your code