# can't pass parameters in react navigation (Drawer navigator)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new in react native . I have a problem with navigation . I have a component (List of News).I need to pass to this component the url of each category of the news.AnThen show the list according to this list.
I need something like this
in app.js

```
const RootStack = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Details: {
      screen: NewsList,
      url:'xxxx'

    },
    Home: {
      screen: NewsList,
      url:'xxxx'

    },
  },
);
```

then I need the value of the url in newsList Component

Comment: Please check this - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator.html#navigator-props

Comment: I suppose the `url`s are just representing pre-defined categories? What's the structure of `url` your are trying to use? You can use `screenProps` (like @Ejaz suggested).

Comment: See the answer to your question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248403/passing-props-with-screen-option-in-drawernavigator?noredirect=1&lq=1