# React-native - passing params with drawerNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been using switchNavigator to navigate between views but now I'm testing out drawerNavigator. With switch it's fairly easy to pass props since I'm navigating through a button, something like this:

```
this.navigate({
    routeName: 'Home',
    key: 'Home',
    params: {
       username: this.state.username
    }
 });
```

It's not done the same way on a drawer though, it seems? So how is it supposed to be done? Thanks

Comment: This has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248403/passing-props-with-screen-option-in-drawernavigator?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to pass the params

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { userName: this.state.username });
```

And you can get the params from the component like this

```
const { userName } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

Comment: Yes, but where do you pass that in the drawer? There's no buttons to pass it on since the drawer have the buttons, unlike in switch where you create the buttons yourself.